# Is there $n>5$ whose factorial in base $2$ is a block of $1$'s then all $0$s?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Each of $1,2,3,4,5$ has its factorial in base $2$ of form$1...10...0.$ I'm wondering if there are greater $n$ for which this occurs. Such $n$ satisfy
$$n!=(2^a-1)2^b,$$
but I wasn't able to show $n\le5$ from this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe not the most elementary solution: 
Let's assume that such $a$ and $b$ exist. By Zsigmondy's theorem there is a prime $p$ dividing $2^a-1$ which does not divide $2^n-1$ for any $n<a$. For such prime we have $ord_p(2)=a$, so $a \mid p-1$ and therefore $a \le p-1$. Since $p \mid n!$ we have $p \le n$ and so $a \le p-1 \le n-1$. Similarly for $b$ we have:
$$b=v_2(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\rfloor < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^k}=n$$ so $b \le n-1$ too. Therefore we have to have:
$$n! \le (2^{n-1}-1)2^{n-1}$$
Which is satisfied only for $n \le 6$ and since $6$ doesn't have this property we are done. This can be generalized to prove that in any system there is only a finite number of factorials which consist of the same digit repeated followed by the string of zeroes.

Comment: This is good-- likely will accept but +1 for now.